# Compute complex integral of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Compute

$$\oint_{\partial B_R(0)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$$

Where $f$ is holomorphic and $a\neq b \in \mathbb{C}$.

My thoughts, use residue theorem to evaluate it obtaining

$$2 \pi i (f(a)+f(b))$$

Or do I need to include the denominator excluding $a$ when evaluating $f(a)$ and vis versa?

But if the radius $R$ is smaller than the modulus of $a,b$ isn't it just zero?

Comment: there are a few cases to consider. $R\in (0,\min(|a|,|b|))$, and $R\in (\min(|a|,|b|), \max(|a|,|b|))$ and $R\in (\max(|a|,|b|),\infty)$.

Comment: ok so im not crazy, there ARE cases. Thanks!

Comment: @peek-a-boo so in your first case, is it just zero? since the winding number is zero? And in the other cases do I calculate the residues?

Comment: what if $a=0,b=1$. Do you get $0$ in the first case? You're probably imagining that $\{0,a,b\}$ is a set of distinct elements. Just work carefully and calculate residues. The slickest approach is probably to just do partial fractions, split it up into two integrals, and then you have a result involving the winding number.

Comment: oh, no cause $a$ has winding number 1! thanks !!!

Comment: @peek-a-boo if $R \in (0,\text{min}(\vert a \vert, \vert b \vert))$ , I have two cases to cover correct? either a or b is zero or their both nonzero? if their both non zero the integral is identically zero, am I correct?

Comment: If one of them is $0$, then the interval is $(0,0)=\emptyset$, so there's nothing to check.

Comment: @peek-a-boo but $R>0$ so if one of them is zero the winding number of radius $R$ is 1 since it wraps around once. and then there the case where $R$ greater or less than $\vert b \vert$ assuming here that $\vert a \vert = 0$